# procmail issue - splitting delivery of one address based on destination domain

Tags: email, procmail

I use [procmail](http://procmail.org) to handle some serverside mail processing. I am trying to setup one email address on a server that support multiple domains (in the example below, `domain.net` and `domain.com`). I want mail sent to `user@domain.net` to go to `bob` and mail sent to `user@domain.com` to go to `sara`.

```
VERBOSE=off
LOGFILE=/dev/null

:0
* .domain.net
bob

:0
* .domain.com
sara
```

The above recipe seems to work quite well in that it catches incoming mail to `domain.net` and forwards it to `bob`.

However, instead of forwarding mail to `domain.com` to `sara`, it creates a file in `/home/user` called `sara`.

What am I doing wrong on this?

Comment: The fundamental problem is "don't do that".  See http://partmaps.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#bcc-explanation

Comment: and the downvote is for ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're delivering to a local file, not forwarding the message on to users. Also (as you pointed out in your comment) you aren't carbon-copying the message, so delivery stops after the first matching rule.

```
# 'c'opy the message to deliver it twice.
# ! to forward the message
:0 c
* .domain.net
! bob

:0
* .domain.com
! sara
```

The prcomailrc manpage says:

> Anything else will be taken as a mailbox name (either a filename or a directory, absolute or
>   relative to the current directory (see MAILDIR)).  If it is  a  (possibly  yet  nonexistent)
>   filename, the mail will be appended to it.

The best way to debug procmail issues is to set `verbose` and `logfile` in your `.procmailrc`.  Examining the logfile will go a long way toward revealing why procmail is acting a particular way.

**EDIT**: Updated with carbon-copy info based on OP comment.

Comment: Yes, without the bang (!) symbol, the recipe says to deliver to local file.

Comment: Also, you might want to use something like ^TOdomain.net to be more precise in your targeting. The recipes as listed (I think) will match any header containing .domain.net or .domain.com, including the subject.

Comment: thanks! the other component I need is a ` c` after the `:0`, so it not looks like `:0 c`.